# android-Timepicker methods getcurrenthour() is deprecated, how to use getHour() in android 4.5 ??

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-timepicker

```
int hours = time.getHours();
int minutes = time.getMinutes();
int seconds = time.getSeconds();
```

These functions are not usable for Android 4.5, how do I use them in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, you use event listener to retrieve current time in mSecs:

Then, later, you retrieve the time in required format. Say, hours:minutes ("HH:mm"):

```
Long newTimeMsecValue = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new 
    TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
         //NOTE: hourOfDay is always in 24h mode, not dependent of AM/PM mode!
          newTimeMsecValue = new Long (((hourOfDay * 3600) + (minute * 60)) * 1000); //
    }});


    Calendar myCalend = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalend.setTimeInMillis(newTimeMsecValue);// value from the code above
        Date calDate = myCalend.getTime();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String humanDate = df.format(calDate);
```

Now : humanDate keeps value like: 10:21

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below-mentioned methods to get the hour from the time picker, and then you can format it in this way:

- `getHour()`
- `getMinutes()`

```
String date = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute());
```